# HDF5 Attributes of External Links only accessible in “r” mode

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

- Python 3.8
- h5py 2.10.0
- Windows 10

I have found that when using any other mode, other than “r”, attributes are not accessible and an error is raised.

`_casa.h5` is the HDF file which contains numerous links to external files.
"/149901/20118/VRM_DATA" is the path to a group within one of the external files.

This works:

```
# open file in read only mode
hfile = h5py.File("..\casa\_data\_casa.h5", “r”)
hfile["/149901/20118/VRM_DATA"].attrs

Out[21]: <Attributes of HDF5 object at 1660502855488>
hfile.close()
```

This does not work:

```
# Open file in Read/write, file must exist mode
hfile = h5py.File("..\casa\_data\_casa.h5", “r+”)
hfile["/149901/20118/VRM_DATA"].attrs

Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Users\HIAPRC\Miniconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py”, line 3418, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File “”, line 1, in
hfile["/149901/20118/VRM_DATA"].attrs
File “h5py_objects.pyx”, line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File “h5py_objects.pyx”, line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File “C:\Users\HIAPRC\Miniconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\group.py”, line 264, in getitem
oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
File “h5py_objects.pyx”, line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File “h5py_objects.pyx”, line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File “h5py\h5o.pyx”, line 190, in h5py.h5o.open
KeyError: “Unable to open object (unable to open external file, external link file name = ‘.\sub_files\casa_2021-01-13_10-03-51.h5’)”
```

I consulted the documentation and Googled around and did not find any answer to this.
Is this a result of design or a bug?

If this is by design then I guess I will have to edit attributes by opening the external file directly and make the changes there.

[EDIT] - HDFView 3.1.1 has no problem opening the `_casa.h5` file, editing and saving edits done on the attributes of groups in external files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file?  Is it writable?

Comment: @JohnGordon - The account I am using to run any code has Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, Read, Write according to the Security tab on its file permissions. Of note is that I can use HDFView 3.1.1 to read and change attributes of externally linked groups without errors. (I will add to question above) Thanks.

Comment: To clarify your schema: you want to access attributes attached to a dataset in the file referenced by the ExternalLink. In other words, NOT with datasets in the `_casa.h5` file, right? (FYI, I can read attributes attached to a dataset in the HDF5 file that has ExternalLinks. I will continue testing the linked files.)

Comment: Followup on above. I added an attribute to datasets referenced by the ExternalLink files. I am able to read them with h5py when I open with either File mode ('r+' or 'r'). I am running Python 3.8.3 with h5py 2.10.0 on Windows 7 (yes old OS).

Comment: @kcw78 You are right. But in fact I cannot get a reference to a group in an external file without an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled code from other SO answers into a single example. The code below creates 3 files, each with a single dataset with an attribute. It then creates another HDF5 file with ExternalLinks to the previously created files. The link objects also have attributes. All 4 files are then reopened in 'r' mode and attributes are accessed and printed. Maybe this will help you diagnose your problem. See below. Note: I am running Python 3.8.3 with h5py 2.10.0 on Windows 7 (Anaconda distribution to be precise).

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

for fcnt in range(1,4,1):
    fname = 'file' + str(fcnt) + '.h5'
    arr = np.random.random(50).reshape(10,5)
    with h5py.File(fname,'w') as h5fw :
        h5fw.create_dataset('data_'+str(fcnt),data=arr)
        h5fw['data_'+str(fcnt)].attrs['ds_attr']='attribute '+str(fcnt)
     
with h5py.File('SO_65705770.h5',mode='w') as h5fw:
    for fcnt in range(1,4,1):    
        h5name = 'file' + str(fcnt) + '.h5'
        link_obj = h5py.ExternalLink(h5name,'/')
        h5fw['link'+str(fcnt)] = h5py.ExternalLink(h5name,'/')
        h5fw['link'+str(fcnt)].attrs['link_attr']='attr '+str(fcnt)

for fcnt in range(1,4,1):
    fname = 'file' + str(fcnt) + '.h5'
    print (fname)
    with h5py.File(fname,'r') as h5fr :
        print( h5fr['data_'+str(fcnt)].attrs['ds_attr'] )

with h5py.File('SO_65705770.h5',mode='r') as h5fr:
    for fcnt in range(1,4,1):    
        print ('file',fcnt,":")
        print('link attr:', h5fr['link'+str(fcnt)].attrs['link_attr'] )
        print('linked ds attr:', h5fr['link'+str(fcnt)]['data_'+str(fcnt)].attrs['ds_attr'] )
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked with 'r' mode. I ran it again and it worked in 'r+' mode! I will have to keep plugging away at my original code. At least this confirms that it *should* work in my setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The h5py documentation on external links was either not clear or I didn't understand it.

Anyway, it turned out that I had not assigned the external links properly.

Why it worked for one mode and not another is beyond me. If the way I did the external link assignment had fail for all modes, I probably would have figured out the cause sooner.

EDIT: What I was doing wrong and how to do it correctly to get what I wanted...

External File and what I want it to look like in the file containing the links.

[image: External file]

What I did wrong.

```
with h5py.File("file_with_links.h5", mode="w") as h5fw:
        
    h5fw["/901/20111/VRM_DATA"] = h5py.ExternalLink(h5name, "/901/20111/VRM_DATA")
```

What I should have done:

```
with h5py.File("file_with_links.h5", mode="w") as h5fw:
        
    h5fw["/901/20111"] = h5py.ExternalLink(h5name, "/901/20111")
```