# How to link HDF5 files generated with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

Assume we have a folder with HDF5-files generated by `pandas.to_hdf`. I would like to create one `master.h5` file that contains external links to all the `DataFrames`.

According to the documentation of `h5py`, the standard way to do this is

```
myfile = h5py.File('master.h5','w')
myfile['ext link'] = h5py.ExternalLink("some_sub_file.h5", "/path/to/resource")
```

But files generated by `pandas.to_hdf` contain not just `datasets`, but `h5py.Groups`. How exactly would you then set up the external link to work?

Answer (score 0):

Links can point to any object in the HDF5 data structure (datasets or groups). The file is a special form of a group; called the root group and referenced with `'/'`. So, to link to a file, use: `h5py.ExternalLink(filename,'/')`.

You didn't say if you want a link for each dataframe/dataset in each file, or links for each file. It's simpler to create links to the file root groups. If you create individual links to the datasets, be sure you assign unique names.

There are 2 answers that demonstrate each method. The questions were not specifically about `h5py.ExternalLink()`, but my answers to each question used external links. See these answers:

- [HDF5 Attributes of External Links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710483/10462884): Creates links to root group in multiple files. (each file only has 1 dataset...but your process would be identical.)
- [I/O Issues in Loading Several Large H5PY Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70103566/10462884) : Creates links to multiple datasets in multiple files. (Requires unique dataset names to work "as-is". Can be modified if names are not unique.)

I modified the code from the second answer (70089964) to show how to create 3 external links from the master file to the root group in 3 files (where each file has 5 datasets).

Code to create 3 example files:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np   
for fcnt in range(3):
    fname = f'file_{fcnt+1}.h5'
    with h5py.File(fname,'w') as h5fw:
        for dscnt in range(1,6,1):
            arr = np.random.random(10).reshape(5,2)
            h5fw.create_dataset(f'data_{fcnt*10+dscnt:02}',data=arr*dscnt)
```

Code to create links from the master file to the 3 files:

```
import h5py
fnames = ['file_1.h5','file_2.h5','file_3.h5']
with h5py.File(f'master_{len(fnames)}_links}.h5','w') as h5fw:   
    for fname in fnames:
        with h5py.File(fname,'r') as h5fr:
                h5fw[fname] = h5py.ExternalLink(fname,'/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional research on Pandas and HDF5 links revealed an interesting discovery: there are limitations with links (you can create them in Pandas, but Pandas can't access the linked data). In other words, the links are there, and work fine with HDFView, h5py and PyTables. Reference these GitHub issues:

- [Pandas hdf functions should support the hdf5 ExternalLink
  functionality when reading/writing - Issue #6019](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6019)
- [Presence of softlink in HDF5 file breaks HDFStore.keys() - Issue
  #20523](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20523)
- Status for both appears to be Open. My tests confirm previously reported errors.

The code below shows how to create both link types. It also shows the error message you will get when you try to access the linked data. (Error message is: `KeyError: 'you cannot get attributes from this 'NoAttrs' instance`. This is due to a HDF5 limitation attribute restrictions on links. a A HDFStore node has some required attributes. Result is the 'NoAttrs' message when Pandas tries to read the attributes.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "a": [1,2,3,4], "b": [11,12,13,14] })
print(df1.to_string())

# Create file 1 with simple dataframe
f1 = "test_1.hdf"
with pd.HDFStore(f1, mode="w") as  hdf1:
    hdf1.put("/key1", df1)

# Create file 2 with external link 
f2 = "test_extlink.hdf"
with pd.HDFStore(f2, mode="w") as hdf2:
    hdf2._handle.create_external_link(hdf2._handle.root, "extlink_key1", f"{f1}:/key1")
    print("Successful external link write")

with pd.HDFStore(f2, mode="r") as hdf2:
    print(hdf2.keys()) # Notice that [] (no keys) is printed
    # following lines will trigger the 'NoAttrs' error message
    # df2test = pd.read_hdf(f2,key="extlink_key1")
    # print(df2test.to_string())
    print("End external link read")

# Create file 3 with simple dataframe and symbolic (soft) link 
f3 = "test_symlink.hdf"    
with pd.HDFStore(f3, mode="w") as hdf3:
    hdf3.put("/key1", df1)
    hdf3._handle.create_soft_link(hdf3._handle.root, "symlink_key1", "/key1")
    print("Successful symbolic link write")
    
with pd.HDFStore(f3, mode="r") as hdf3:
    print(hdf3.keys()) # Notice that only ['key1'] is printed
    # following lines will trigger the 'NoAttrs' error message
    # df3test = pd.read_hdf(f3,key="symlink_key1")
    # print(df3test.to_string())
    print("End symbolic link read")
```